# Tkinter get child widget on creation

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the widget that has just been created in a frame.

Using either the  or  bindings will trigger **only** if I am binding `root (r)`, if I bind the `Frame (a)` then no event is triggered when creating new widgets inside.

```py
from tkinter import *

def test(event):
    print(event, event.widget)

def add(w):
    w.bind('<Configure>', test)
    y = Button(w, text="Hello")
    z = Button(w, text="World")
    y.pack(side=TOP)
    z.pack(side=TOP)

r = Tk()
r.geometry("400x400+100+100")


a = Frame(r)
a.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=1)

w1=r
w2=a

b=Button(r, text="make new", command=lambda :add(w1)) ##switch w1 to w2 to see differences
b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

r.mainloop()
```

I don't think I could filter through the 10,000's of events triggered to somehow pick out the few I need without causing both high memory usage and huge lag.

Is there some way if triggering a configure event automatically when a widget is created inside?

Comment: Since the frame has already been expanded to fill the window, so adding widget to it may not adjust its size.

Comment: You could get the last child of the `Frame` with `a.winfo_chlidren()[-1]`, but note that this will raise an `IndexError` the first time because `a` doesn't have any children (yet) so you'll want to wrap the query in a `Try: ... Except IndexError: pass` block

Comment: @JRiggles unfortunately that is not an event, it would have to be input by the user for every widget they have created. Im looking for something to auto-trigger on creation of a widget and call a method with the widget object being one of the args. In the example this is what the root <Configure> event does but it only activates for the root widget.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you would put the query to `winfo_children()` inside the event handler function. It's not a perfect solution, as you may end up calling it more often since it's bound to `root`

Comment: @JRiggles yes. I would like to somehow create a <<Child_Map>> event for the parent widget. Adding this to root would require getting the path i want to chech, looping through all children and checking if i have already added them to a list and if not run a custom command for that child. This would require a lot of processing during actions as simple as moving the window and as such cause a lot of lag in the UI.